# Playing sound on Rails server on request of Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to play music files on server machine which is connected to a stereo system but on the request of a client side.

The client opens the web app through the URL and click play and the sound play on the server machine. (I don't want to stream)

At the moment my sound file is located in the same directory as the Controller but when I press the play button from a browser nothing happen.

This might be very straightforward but as a Beginner I am finding it difficult to execute system command on the host.

So far I have this client interface on **localhost:3000**
[image]

I have a controller defined which handles the request from play button.

class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
    def index
    end

```
def play
  `mplayer myfile.mp3`
  head :ok
end
```

end

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'welcome#index'
  get "/play" => "welcome#play"
end
```

Output of Rake Routes

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern     Controller#Action
root GET  /               welcome#index
play GET  /play(.:format) welcome#play
```

Index.html.erb

```
<h1>Play it!</h1>
<%= link_to "Play", play_path, remote: true %>
```

Comment: You could use the html5 player: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video

Comment: add `byebug` to your Gemfile, save the shell response to a variable `res = \`mplayer myfile.mp3\`` and put a `byebug` after that line. Then run your server again and click the link. You should hit  a breakpoint and be able to debug what's going on with your shell command

Comment: @toddmetheny I don't want to play the audio files on client side, I want it to be played on the Linux machine in which Rails server is hosted.

Comment: You can still host the actual file on the server side...you want the end user to hear it, correct?

Comment: Thank you guys, I figured it out. I was missing a package and the path to the sound file was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing mplayer package in my linux host and the path to my sound file was incorrect.

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

And I placed the file in the controller's directory thinking the files would be rooted from there, actually the file was being searched at the root directory of the rails app.